# How to insert state/props in class attribute in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I am working on reactjs , I had a little experience in meteorjs before and I used to do like

`<p class= {somehelper}> testing </p>`

but here in reactjs it is not working like this.Here is sample of code.

```
<div className="col-md-3 {card.insertTime}"> DeadLine :  {card.insertTime}</div>
```

Here `{card.insertTime}`  is not giving value .what is the mistake I am doing.

Answer (score 3):

```
<div className="col-md-3 {card.insertTime}">
```

Is treating `"col-md-3 {card.insertTime}"` as a literal string. You need to do string concatenation instead:

```
<div className="col-md-3 " + card.insertTime>
```

A good best practice is to always wrap strings in `{}` to make assignment clear:

```
<div className={"col-md-3 " + card.insertTime}>
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case you can use string concatenation,

```
<div className={ "col-md-3 " + card.insertTime }>Concat</div>
```

or if you use `ES2015`you can use [`template literals`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```
<div className={ `col-md-3 ${ card.insertTime }` }>template</div>
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/38284/)